# matching but not including one or the other with python regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have data that is in the following format:

```
<Category: XXX &nbsp;-&nbsp;
```

or

```
<Category: XXX</b>
```

---

I woud like to retain the 'xxx' only, but have ony been able to retain ('XXX','') or ('')or other un-desired variations.

**I do not want to use beautiful soup, I'm having trouble downloading it with my anaconda package manager**

---

**ADDED - My attempts**

```
'Category: ([^<]+)</b'
```

would yield ['xxx'] when

```
<Category: XXX</b>
```

---

```
'Category: ([^<]+) &n'
```

would yield ['xxx'] when

```
<Category: XXX &nbsp;
```

and I think I did something like

```
'Category: ([^<]+)(</b| &n)'
```

that yielded

```
[('XXX', '</b')]
```

or

```
[('XXX', ' &nb')]
```

Comment: Could you include some more code that you've been trying so far and some sample input data in your question?

Comment: ummm `re.findall("Category:\s(\W+)",my_text)` something like that?

Comment: ok adding some to main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('<Category:\s(\w+)', "<Category: XXX</b>").group(1)
'XXX'
>>> re.match('<Category:\s(\w+)', "<Category: XXX &nbsp;-&nbsp;").group(1)
'XXX'
```

or using `findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('<Category:\s(\w+)', "<Category: XXX &nbsp;-&nbsp;")[0]
'XXX'
>>> re.findall('<Category:\s(\w+)', "<Category: XXX</b>")[0]
'XXX'
```

- `\s` matches any whitespace character.
- `\w` matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the set `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`.
- `\w+` matches one or more any non-alphanumeric characters.
- `(...)` is a capturing group:

> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and
>   indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be
>   retrieved after a match has been performed

See [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for more info.

Comment: \s(\w+) works, that's all I *really* care about, but if you could explain, I would read and appreciate